# if ... function.start - if ... function.end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function here, as soon as the highscore is cracked, a fireworks display is played. Now I want the fireworks to stop as soon as the Start button is clicked again. Do I need an IF condition associated with the Start button, or what would that look like in the code?

I don't know the command, I tried firework.end, but it didn't work.

```
fireworks.start(); //Start the fireworks.
```

As I said, I would like the fireworks to stop as soon as a new game is started (so click the Start button).

Comment: Please trim your question down to a [MCVE], and explain your problem in more detail. 307 lines of code is too much.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I posted the whole function so you could see what kind of function I created.

The problem is the line: fireworks.start() , how to terminate this function again.

Comment: Your edit does not make it a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read on how to create that. Also please edit your title to summarize your problem

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking for a way to terminate the event loop which causes the firework to be displayed. There is no way to terminate a function. You should post the code for `firework.end` and `firework.start` so we can help sort out the problem.

Comment: From your original code, it looks like `_addExplosion` calls itself - so you could add a function `end`, which sets a boolean to false, and only if this boolean is true, will `_addExplosion` call itself again.

Comment: Right now I'm trying like this: `function highScore1(score) {if (score > saved5 ) {
    saved5 = score;
    localStorage.setItem('highScore', score);
    document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = saved5; fireworks.start();` And here I want to end the firework: `("#start").click(function() { 
  localStorage.clear(); fireworks.end`

Comment: It should be like this: whenever your firework starts, it will reset all states to normal that is ready to start the firework and after that really starts the firework. So, you don't have to worry when the Start button is clicked.

Comment: You trimmed it down a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_addExplosion`calls itself recursively, so by adding another property called `_running`, we can flip this in a function called `stop`:

```
stop: function() {
    this._running = false;
    window.clearTimeout();
    for (var i = 0; i < this._particles.length; i++) {
        this._particles[i].parentNode.removeChild(this._particles[i]);
    }
},
```

Inside `_addExplosion` we can inspect this to stop the "loop":

```
if (this._running) {
    window.setTimeout(function () { return fireworks._addExplosion.apply(fireworks); },
            this._random(this._interval[1] - this._interval[0]) + this._interval[0]);
}
```

You can then declare a function to be executed on click:

```
function stopFireworks() {
    fireworks.stop();
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<button onclick="stopFireworks()">Stop</button>
```

Full example:

```js
var fireworks = {

            ///////////////////////////// configuration ////////////////////////////

            // random colors
            _color: ['#D0D0D0', '#FF0000', '#FFFF00', '#22FF00', '#2040FF', '#00CCFF', '#FF00FF', '#A319D6'],
            // gravity factor
            _gravity: 0.07,
            // air resistance factor
            _resistance: 0.975,
            // zIndex of particles
            _zIndex: 20000,
            // maximal age of particles (in msec)
            _maxAge: 2000,
            // interval of appearing explosions (in msec)
            _interval: [500, 2500],
            // amount of particles per explosion
            _particlesPerExplosion: 40,
            // maximal speed of particle at moment of explosion
            _speed: 5,
            // minimal/maximal size of particle
            _minSize: 8,
            _maxSize: 12,
            _running: true,



            ///////////////////////////// private vars /////////////////////////////

            _particles: [],
            _bodyWidth: 0,
            _bodyHeight: 0,
            _count: 0,
            _lastInterval: 0,



            ////////////////////////////// functions ///////////////////////////////

            // init fireworks
            init: function () {
                this._addEventListener(window, 'resize', function () { return fireworks.resize.apply(fireworks); });
                this._addEventListener(window, 'load', function () { return fireworks.start.apply(fireworks); });
            },


            // add an event listener
            _addEventListener: function (el, name, handler) {
                if (el.addEventListener)
                    el.addEventListener(name, handler, false);
                else if (el.attachEvent)
                    el.attachEvent('on' + name, handler);
            },


            // start fireworks
            start: function () {
                // init window size
                this.resize();

                // start to move particles
                this._animFn = function () { fireworks._move(); };
                this._lastInterval = this._time();
                requestAnimFrame(this._animFn);

                this._addExplosion();
            },


            // get current time
            _time: function () {
                return +new Date();
            },


            // return a random integer
            _random: function (value) {
                return Math.random() * value;
            },


            // return a random array element
            _randomArray: function (arr) {
                return arr[
                    Math.floor(
                        Math.random() * (arr.length)
                    )
                ];
            },


                // add a new explosion
            _addExplosion: function () {
                var x = Math.floor(this._random(this._bodyWidth)),
                    y = Math.floor((this._random(.5) + .1) * this._bodyHeight),
                    dx = this._random(10) - 5,
                    dy = this._random(-2) - 1,
                    c1 = this._randomArray(this._color),
                    c2 = this._randomArray(this._color);

                    for (var i = 0; i < this._particlesPerExplosion; i++) {
                        if (this._running) {
                            this._createParticle(
                                x,
                                y,
                                dx,
                                dy,
                                i / (this._particlesPerExplosion - 1) * 180 * Math.PI,
                                this._random(this._speed),
                                this._random(1) > .5 ? c1 : c2
                            );
                        }
                    }
                if (this._running) {
                    window.setTimeout(
                        function () {
                            fireworks._addExplosion.apply(fireworks);
                        }, 
                        this._random(this._interval[1] - this._interval[0]) + this._interval[0]
                    );
                }
            },
            
            stop: function() {
                this._running = false;
                window.clearTimeout();
                for (var i = 0; i < this._particles.length; i++) {
                    this._particles[i].parentNode.removeChild(this._particles[i]);
                }
            },

            // creates a new particle
            _createParticle: function (x, y, dx, dy, rot, speed, color) {
                var el = null,
                    foundEl = false,
                    p = this._particles;

                // look for old particle
                for (var i = 0, l = p.length; i < l; i++)
                    if (p[i].data.age > 1) {
                        el = p[i];
                        foundEl = true;
                        break;
                    }

                // create span child for particles
                if (!foundEl) {
                    el = document.createElement('div');
                    el.className = 'particle';
                    el.style.position = 'absolute';
                    el.style.fontSize = this._maxSize + 'px';
                    el.style.zIndex = this._zIndex;
                    el.style.width = this._maxSize + 'px';
                    el.style.textAlign = 'center';
                    el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                    el.innerHTML = '&#x25cf;';
                }

                el.style.left = x + 'px';
                el.style.top = y + 'px';
                el.style.color = color;
                el.data = {
                    x: x,
                    y: y,
                    dx: Math.cos(rot) * speed + dx,
                    dy: Math.sin(rot) * speed + dy,
                    color: color,
                    age: Math.random() * .25
                };

                if (!foundEl) {
                    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(el);
                    this._particles.push(el);
                }
            },


            // move existing particles
            _move: function () {
                requestAnimFrame(this._animFn);

                // calculate movement factor
                var dif = this._time() - this._lastInterval;
                this._lastInterval = this._time();

                var delta = dif / 20,
                    el,
                    d,
                    p = this._particles,
                    r = Math.pow(this._resistance, delta),
                    g = this._gravity * delta,
                    a = dif / this._maxAge;

                for (var i = 0, l = p.length; i < l; i++) {
                    el = p[i];
                    d = el.data;

                    if (d.age > 1)
                        continue;

                    d.age += a;
                    d.dy += g;
                    d.dx *= r;
                    d.dy *= r;
                    d.x += d.dx * delta;
                    d.y += d.dy * delta;

                    if (d.x < 0) {
                        d.dx *= -1;
                        d.x = 0;
                    }
                    else if (d.x > this._bodyWidth) {
                        d.dx *= -1;
                        d.x = this._bodyWidth;
                    }
                    if (d.y < 0) {
                        d.dy *= -1;
                        d.y = 0;
                    }
                    else if (d.y > this._bodyHeight) {
                        d.dy *= -1;
                        d.y = this._bodyHeight;
                    }

                    if (d.age > 1)
                        d.x = d.y = 0;

                    el.style.left = d.x + 'px';
                    el.style.top = d.y + 'px';
                    el.style.color = (Math.random() * .5 + d.age >= 1) ? 'transparent' : d.color;
                    el.style.fontSize = Math.max(this._minSize, (1 - d.age) * this._maxSize) + 'px';
                }
            },


            // calculate new positions for all particles
            resize: function () {
                // get new width and height
                this._bodyWidth = this._getWindowWidth() - this._maxSize;
                this._bodyHeight = this._getWindowHeight() - this._maxSize - 10;
            },


            // get window width
            _getWindowWidth: function () {
                return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].offsetWidth;
            },


            // get window height
            _getWindowHeight: function () {
                var h = Math.max(self.innerHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0);

                if (document.documentElement)
                    h = Math.max(h, document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0);
                if (document.body) {
                    h = Math.max(h, document.body.clientHeight || 0);
                    h = Math.max(h, document.body.scrollHeight || 0);
                    h = Math.max(h, document.body.offsetHeight || 0);
                }

                return h;
            }

        };

        // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (cb) {
                    window.setTimeout(cb, 1000 / 60);
                };
        })();

        function stopFireworks() {
            fireworks.stop();
        }
        fireworks.start();
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

    <button onclick="stopFireworks()">Stop</button>  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your suggested solution is very good so far, but it doesn't finish the fireworks. I don't want to create a button for it, I don't want the player to know about it. I tried this variant, but unfortunately it doesn't work:
`<button id="start" onclick="stopFireworks()" type=button >Start</button>` The idea is that the Start button is also used as a function to stop the fireworks.

Comment: Even with the Stop button I can't stop the fireworks. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: @sharete Did you try running the code-snippet here on SO? I works for me - some times an extra explosion happens, something I thought `window.clearTimeout();` would take care of. You can add more to the function, e.g running through every particle in `this._particles`, removing them from the DOM.

Comment: I updated the answer with the code to completely remove the particles.